# Hide scrollbar with css not working on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to hide the scrollbar with css but it works on firefox but in Chrome the scrollbar is still there

```
.tests-container{
    @media (min-width: 1025px) {
        max-height: 600px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        :-webkit-scrollbar{
            display: none;
        }
        -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
        scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a media query inside a class, so I'll change to this

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .tests-container {
      max-height: 600px;
      /* overflow-y: scroll; */

      -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
      scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
  }
  
  .tests-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I made an example here https://codepen.io/dshung1997/pen/MWeMOYB. It worked fine on my laptop, Chrome MacOS